# Using ag-grid react-data-grid react version 27.2 enterprise. ScrollbarIssue on agSelectCellEditor on edit mode

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-data-grid

using ag-grid react version 27.2 enterprise. While working on agSelectCellEditor on edit mode, the moment I click on scrollbar of opened dropdown to scroll the select options, dropdown closes

Comment: We can't help until you can provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example